# webview full page load in customScrollView Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to add `webview` inside `customScrollView`.

```
child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    setAppBar(),
                     SliverFillRemaining(
                         child: InAppWebView(
                         initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
          )),
                  ],
                )
```

the problem is only visble area is webview loading ...remaining content is not visible/scrollable..

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping InAppwebView Widget with a SingleChildScrollView and set physics like this... The FillRemaining is not needed

```
...
slivers: <Widget>[
 setAppBar(),
 SliverList(
 delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
 SingleChildScrollView(
 physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
 child:InAppWebView(
    ...
```

UPDATED Answer:

This will work in simple cases. But in your case, I think you need NestedScrollView() widget to show a dynamic height widget like PageView / WebView below the SliverAppBar. You can check this code https://flutteragency.com/nestedscrollview-widget/

Comment: not working ...
s[96829:1257145] flutter: RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
[96829:1257145] flutter: This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
s[96829:1257145] flutter: inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

Comment: try the new code, I updated the answer, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Bro, I updated the answer. You can check that way. I got it helpful.

Comment: Same even with nested controller